# How to prevent signal waveform from going towards negative side when increasing gain

Tags: operational-amplifier, signal, power-electronics, signal-processing

I have managed to design a circuit: [image]
that is able to read an ECG signal where the signal is then acquired through a DAQ called TiePie. From there, the signal is then digitally processed (HPF,50Hz removal,etc), through MATLAB. Everything is fine. However the problem now is that when I tried to increase the gain, the Vpp of the waveform remains the same but the waveform starts to shift lower towards the negative side. A friend of mine told me to put in an AC coupling DC bias level stage, [image]

I added this right after JP3. It works well and maintain the waveform signal at 0 axis when read on the oscilloscope. However, when I tried to increase the gain of the signal, it only increase by a few mV. Can anyone tell me whats wrong or is the so called AC coupling DC bias level is wrong ? Is there any better alternatives ?

Also I am supplying the circuit with 1 x 9V battery where the supply is split to +4.5V and -4.5V.

Answer (score 0):

Any of the issues below could be relevant (and probably are)

- The recommended power supply operating range for the TL071 op-amp is +/- 5 volts to +/- 15 volts - you seem to be saying it runs from +/- 4.5 volts.
- The output swing capabilities of the TL071 are guaranteed to be +/- 12 volts on a +/- 15 volt rail so that means, on a +/- 4.5 volt rail, the output swing might only be +/- 1.5 volts.

So there's a couple of things to think about.

Comment: thanks for pointing that out. This circuit will eventually be powered by +/- 9 volts. However, the issue is, at lowest gain in AD620, the Vpp is at +/- 140mV. So when I increased the gain at RG, I am not expecting a significant increase but the signal Vpp only increase to +/- 220mV, any more the signal will saturates or only a straight line is seen on the oscilloscope. Why is that so ? Also, is the so called AC coupling stage correct ? I am using a polarized capacitor by the way. I heard that it is best to put a ceramic capacitor. So which do I use  ?